# Floating a block-level element inside a paragraph

Tags: html, css

I'm writing a compiler from a high-level document to HTML. Basically, I want:

```
Because blah blah{{margin-note|...}}, it yada yada.
```

to compile to the following paragraph:

```
Because blah blah¹, it yada yada.
```

and with a box floating on the right of the paragraph in the same level as the margin note number.

The way I approached this is to compile it to the following HTML:

```
<p>
  Because blah blah<span class="mg-note-num">1</span><span class="mg-note-box">...</span>, it yada yada.
</p>
```

where `mg-note-box` shifts the element to the right of the paragraph. This works really well, except that the margin note box couldn't support block-level elements, like `ul`. When I put `ul` inside the margin note box, the `ul` element will be thrown outside of the `span` tag.

The obvious fix is to change `span` to `div` so that `ul` can stay inside the `div`, but this is not an option either because `div` can't stay inside `p`. Doing so will break the paragraph into two. Instead of:

```
Because blah blah¹, it yada yada.
```

we would have this instead

```
Because blah blah¹

, it yada yada.
```

I guess another option is to have a collection phase in my compiler, and move all margin note boxes outside of paragraph. This is also undesirable because for a long paragraph, the position of the margin note boxes will no longer match margin note numbers.

How should I approach this?

---

Update: I should have mentioned that my experiments with `inline-block` also don't work, but perhaps I did it wrong. Here are what I did:

Let's start with a reference layout (which functions properly but doesn't support block-level elements)

```
<p>
  before
  <span style="float: right;">Hello world</span>
  after
</p>
```

This results in

```
| before after             Hello world |
```

With `div` and `inline-block`:

```
<p>
  before
  <div style="float: right; display: inline-block;">Hello world</div>
  after
</p>
```

This results in:

```
| before                        |
|                               |
| after             Hello world |
```

With `span` and `inline-block`:

```
<p>
  before
  <span style="float: right; display: inline-block;">
    <ul><li>1</li></ul>
  </span>
  after
</p>
```

This results in:

```
| before                        |
|                               |
| - 1                           |
|                               |
| after                         |
```

So, no, `inline-block` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: Show the CSS you're using as well.

Comment: Can you make the div `display: inline-block`?

Comment: _the position of the margin note boxes will no longer match margin note numbers_ if you have accessibility concerns you could always use https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/Accessibility/ARIA/ARIA_Techniques/Using_the_aria-describedby_attribute and I would move definitely the notes outside

Comment: @fcalderan don’t think they have accessibility concerns here, more layout concerns - _“a box floating on the right of the paragraph in the same level as the margin note number”_ - getting that box to show on the same “line”/ y-position as the little ¹, that’s the main issue here.

Comment: @misorude is right.

Comment: @John: please see my updated question above. I showed why `display: inline-block` doesn't seem to work.

Comment: @connexo: the actual CSS that does the work is simply `float: right;`, though I think that it's not relevant here. The main problem, I think, is that that layout I have seems to be fundamentally nonsensible w.r.t. HTML semantics.

Comment: Are you looking for something like [this](https://codepen.io/anon/pen/EGYgRR)?

Comment: @John no, see the reference layout above in my question.

Comment: @SoraweePorncharoenwase oops, would have helped if I had saved my pen, sorry!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

My friend, [Pavel Panchekha](https://pavpanchekha.com), found another method that doesn't need to change `<p>` to `<div>`: use `<object>` instead of `<span>`:

```css
p {
  font-family: Arial;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 120px;
}

.note-num {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0 1px 0 -3px;
}

.note-content {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.note-content ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  <sup class="note-num">1</sup>
  <object class="note-content">
    <ul><li>Block Note</li></ul>
  </object>
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

Answer (score 2):

The requirement to handle block elements within a paragraph (this is the important part) is the root of the issue.

***Nesting a block element in a paragraph is not possible.*** [Paragraphs](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/HTML/Element/p) are block-level elements, and automatically close if another block-level element is parsed before the closing `</p>` tag. For example, this HTML:

```
<p>Before<div>Block</div>After</p>
```

results in:

```
<p>Before</p>
<div>Block</div>
<p>After</p>
```

which causes the break around the block element.

The only HTML structure that will achieve the result you want is to use an inline element like a `<span>` (without any nested block elements). Here's an example:

```css
p {
  font-family: Arial;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 120px;
}

.note-num {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0 1px 0 -3px;
}

.note-content {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  max-width: 100px;
}
```

```html
<p>
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  <sup class="note-num">1</sup>
  <span class="note-content">
    Inline Note
  </span>
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</p>
```

### However....

There's one way we can kinda achieve the result you want, which is to use a `<div>` in place of the wrapping `<p>`. Like this:

```css
p,
.p {
  font-family: Arial;
  position: relative;
  padding-right: 120px;
}

.note-num {
  font-size: 10px;
  margin: 0 1px 0 -3px;
}

.note-content {
  position: absolute;
  right: 0;
  font-size: 12px;
  max-width: 100px;
}

.note-content ul {
  margin: 0;
  padding: 0;
}
```

```html
<div class="p">
  Lorem ipsum dolor sit amet, consectetur adipiscing elit, sed do eiusmod tempor incididunt ut labore et dolore magna aliqua. Ut enim ad minim veniam, quis nostrud exercitation ullamco laboris nisi ut aliquip ex ea commodo consequat.
  <sup class="note-num">1</sup>
  <span class="note-content">
    <ul><li>Block Note</li></ul>
  </span>
  Duis aute irure dolor in reprehenderit in voluptate velit esse cillum dolore eu fugiat nulla pariatur. Excepteur sint occaecat cupidatat non proident, sunt in culpa qui officia deserunt mollit anim id est laborum.
</div>
```

Comment: Wow, this is really nice! Is there any drawback to this approach?

Answer (score -2):

Try adding `display: inline-block` to your `<span>`'s style...

See: https://www.w3schools.com/cssref/pr_class_display.asp